# Digitally Sign a PDF using iText from HSM

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, hsm

I want to digitally sign a PDF document using the signature provided by a service which interacts with HSM to fetch primary key and generates a signature. I went through this link [C4_01_SignWithPKCS11HSM.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-4#873-c4_01_signwithpkcs11hsm.java)

but in this example the primary key is exposed to the signer client:

```
ExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, provider);
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, estimatedSize, subfilter);
```

In My use case, I will not be having primary key details, I will just send SHA256 digest of my pdf document to the external service which will interact with HSM to get primary key details and return me a hexadecimal signature which I need to embed in my pdf, this is the only information I have, I couldn't find the way to do it using iText.

Comment: What version of iText are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.5.11 version:

Comment: Although `pk` is an instance of the `PrimaryKey` class, it doesn't *expose* the primary key. If you would share the complete code, Stack Overflow users would notice that you're using a PKCS#11 key store: `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");` PKCS#11 is the standard that explains how to create a signature on an external device (obviously without extracting the private key from that device). I don't think anyone can provide a better example than the one you already have. That example was tested on an HSM and it works the way you want it to work.

Comment: @Fildor No, that article *certainly won't help!* Why not? Because it uses an obsolete version of iTextSharp that involves SHA-1. As you should know, SHA-1 once used to be safe, but SHA-1 was deprecated by NIST in 2011, and recently, SHA-1 was successfully broken. Read [Are PDF Signatures shattered?](http://itextpdf.com/blog/are-pdf-signatures-shattered) for more info. The article you shared was useful in 2006, when it was written, but it would be a huge mistake to keep on using it today. So I suggest that you remove your comment.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I didn't look very deep into the article. Didn't realize it uses SHA1. Couldn't it be adapted to use a proper Hash instead with quite the same code?

Comment: Reading Bruno's link I came across that iText has an eBook for download regarding this topic: http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-digital-signatures-for-pdf.html

Comment: @Fildor All the subtypes that were used in that old version will be deprecated in PDF 2.0. The new subtypes that are now "the standard" didn't exist in 2006. They are based on the PAdES standard, and that standard was only introduced in 2009. You'd need to rewrite the whole digital signatures code, which is what we did in later versions of iText and iTextSharp. That's the long answer ;-) The short answer is "no, you couldn't adapt that article; it should be rewritten."

Comment: Good to know. Thanks Bruno.

Comment: *"return me a hexadecimal signature"* - what kind of signature? A PKCS#1 nearly naked signature? Or a PKCS#7 / CMS signature container?